# Это хороший синтаксис? [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity3d

Является ли этот синтаксис хорошим и эффективным, или же стоит получать компоненты в методе Start?

```
private Rigidbody2D Rb => GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    private Player Player => GetComponent<Player>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ничем не отличается от обычного вызова `GetComponent`. Rb в данном случае это просто:

```
private Rigidbody2D Rb { get { return GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); } }
```

Мы получаем компоненты в методе старт не для того, чтобы был синтаксис лучше, а для того, чтобы закэшировать какой-то компонент, к которому будем часто обращаться. Так как `GetComponent` затратная по времени операция, то очень частое его использование может привести к потере производительности

Comment: то есть всё таки данный синтаксис приемлим?

Comment: Когда я хэширую через старт, то получается, GetComponent вызывается один раз. А если я буду использовать синтаксис с => то он будет вызываться каждый раз при использовании компонента? Если да, то это не приемлимо.

Comment: Да, когда кэшируете через старт, `GetComponent` вызывается один раз. Используя оператор `=>`, `GetComponent` будет вызываться каждый раз при использовании компонента.

Comment: похоже на стрелочную функцию из жабаскрипта